# Current image flickers back after fade out in javascript carousel

Tags: javascript, image, animation, carousel, preload

I am building a image carousel with fade in/out animation with javascript and jquery.

Before the next images fades in, the current image shows up briefly although it's faded out. This happens even though I use onload to make sure the next image is loaded and sized properly. 
(The live code is: www.jbkphotographs.com/nepal.html)

```
function moveToNextImg(){
    if(current === imgArray.length-1){
        current = 0;
    }
    else{
        current++;
    }
    updateIndex();

     //#imgWrapper is <div> that contains <img>
    $("#imgWrapper").fadeOut("slow",loadImg);
}


function loadImg(){

    imgName = imgArray[current].getAttribute("src");
    nextImg.src = imgName.replace("_Thumb","");

    nextImg.id = "currentImg";
    nextImg.onload =  function(){

        if((nextImg.height) > (nextImg.width)){
            nextImg.style.width = "42.5%"
        }

        else{
            nextImg.style.width = '750px';  
        }

        imgWrapper.appendChild(nextImg);


    }
    $("#imgWrapper").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw it. You have that effects befause you are fading in the image before it has been loaded.

a) You should preload the images , before sliding to have the fadein 
   fadeout effect

b) Otherwise put the fade in effect in the onload
   callback of the images:

```
function moveToNextImg(){
    if(current === imgArray.length-1){
        current = 0;
    }  else {
        current++;
    }
    updateIndex();

     //#imgWrapper is <div> that contains <img>
    $("#imgWrapper").fadeOut("slow",loadImg);
}


function loadImg(){

    imgName = imgArray[current].getAttribute("src");
    nextImg.src = imgName.replace("_Thumb","");

    nextImg.id = "currentImg";
    //This code will run only when images will be loaded
    nextImg.onload =  function(){

        if((nextImg.height) > (nextImg.width)){
            nextImg.style.width = "42.5%"
        }

        else{
            nextImg.style.width = '750px';  
        }

        imgWrapper.appendChild(nextImg);

        $("#imgWrapper").fadeIn("slow");
    }

    //any code here will run immediately before the onload runs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quick question: in my original code, fadeIn follows after onload. Doesn't this ensure that fadeIn happens after image is loaded even though it's not included inside the onload event handler?

Comment: onload event is asynchronous, it will run when image will load, it is not linear to the code, everything outside onload  will run immediately